# Is there an online map or other resource that lists windmills in the Netherlands?

Tags: online-resources, netherlands, maps

I would like to know if there is an online map or other reource that lists windmills in the Netherlands. Preferably ones that can be visited. If there information about their former function that would be a plus. 
I would like to visit a "water pomp" windmill. [image: windmill netherlands]

Comment: Are you interested in any specific area? Many of them can be visited nowadays.

Comment: @Bernhard I didn't think of any area in particular. I thought they were evenely spreaded around the country. I might prefer center/south. But it's not a requirement at all.

Comment: Most of the water pumping mills are in the low lying areas in the west and north of the country.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a website called called [allemolens.nl](http://www.allemolens.nl/). "Alle molens" is dutch for all mills. Based on the name only, I would say that this is the resource that you are looking for. Unfortunately the page is Dutch only. It states

> Hier vindt u informatie over alle molens in Nederland, bestaand en verdwenen.

Which translates to:

> This resource contains information about all mills of the Netherlands, both the ones that still exists and those that got demolished.

For a non-dutch speaker the website might not be that informative, although google translate might help you a bit. 
They do have a [search engine](http://collecties.allemolens.nl/atlantispubliek/sub_zoeken.aspx), but again, you need to locate a dutch speaker for it to be effective.

If you are specifically interested in windmills that are called "polder mills", that is that they serve a purpose in draining the gained land in the Netherlands, I can recommend the [Zuiderzee museum](http://www.zuiderzeemuseum.nl/en/10/home/). They have a mill in their collection and you can see the underlying principle by leveraging some water yourself.

The more touristic solution would be to visit the [kinderdijk](https://www.kinderdijk.com/):

[image: Kinderdijk in the Netherlands] Source: [Wikimedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KinderdijkMolens02.jpg).

There is an annual "[windmill day](http://www.molens.nl/site/nationale-molendag/content.php?cid=317&sub=310)" where alle the 950 windmills in the Netherlands will be in action. On that day you can visit many windmills. For 2014 the dates are may 10th/11th.