# Is it possible to visit a water pumping windmill and a industrial windmill at the same location

Tags: netherlands

In the Netherlands you will find many places with several windmills in a small area.
Mostly those are all industrial mills or all water-moving mills.
I know there are some small water-moving windmills in [the Zaanse Schans](http://www.dezaanseschans.nl/en/), but those are of kinds you can not visit inside.

Does anybody know of both kinds of windmill near each other, near being walking distance, say about a kilometer or 2/3 mile apart.

By preference in the Netherlands, elsewhere might be of interest as well.
And of course open to the public at least part of the time.

Comment: Do you mean an industrial windmill like the windmills used to produce Jenever in Schiedam or do you mean a modern pumping station to move water industrially?

Comment: @Relaxed I mean old fashioned windmills that do something other than pump water, for the industrial ones and the old fashioned ones that pump water for the water moving ones. Not modern nor even steam driving 'mills'.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26133/is-there-an-online-map-or-other-resource-that-lists-windmills-in-the-netherlands

Comment: Not an answer to this question. But a rare mill: https://www.kilsdonksemolen.nl/ This is a combination of a wind driven industrial mill and a water driven industrial mill, in Heeswijk-Dinther.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out there is a website that answers your questions right here: [link](http://www.molendatabase.nl/nederland/).
Here you can search per province, the site is in dutch but google translate can help you there.
However judging by your name I'm guessing you are dutch yourself.


In the province of Utrecht in Loenen aan de Vecht there is 
De Hoop (graanmolen), it is maybe a 1 km walk to the Loenderveense Molen (poldermolen) and you can visit them both on saturdays.

Comment: +1 for the search site (I am indeed Dutch) but the two mills you name are both water pumping mills.

Comment: Hi @Willeke I edited my answer and added two mills that seem to fit your question